# substitude a variable string from script to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

This could be a silly question , please bear with me :

I am using ajax to load a json file which then shows data in high charts : code is as follow :

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "{% static 'money/data/highchartpiesam.json' %}",
    success: function (json) {
        console.log("haha i have read the json")
        console.log('Success', this.url)
        $('#containerHighChartJSONPie').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: 1, //null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Expenses per Types of Expenditures'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                        style: {
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Type of Expenditure',
                data: json
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

This code works great as desired but if you see url in above code its : **url: "{% static 'money/data/highchartpiesam.json' %}"**
file name for user so file for sam is highchartpiesam.json , for ram is highchartpieram.json etc 
i.e. file name will be different for different user ( as per my django code) and logged in user name will be appended to work highchartpie.json

In order to make this work i thought to create a url string and then put that string to url: but that doesnt seems to work :(

what i did is changed the above code to following :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("aah document is loaded ")
    console.log("File Name code");
    var a = '{\% static '.concat('\'money/data/highchartpie').concat('{{ user.username }}').concat('.json\'').concat("%}");
    console.log("File Name code : Value of initial string is a is ", a);
    var chartFileName = a;
    $.ajax({

        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        url: chartFileName,
        success: function (json) {
            console.log("haha i have read the json")
            console.log('Success', this.url)
            $('#containerHighChartJSONPie').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: 1, //null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Expenses per Types of Expenditures'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                            style: {
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Type of Expenditure',
                    data: json
                }]
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I still get connsole.log output till :

> "File Name code : Value of initial string is a is " "{% static 'money/data/highchartpiesam.json'%}"

but nothing after that .

Can anyone advise on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't possibly work. Surely you realize that template tags are processed on the backend, and only the rendered content is sent to the browser? There's no point getting JS to generate a string that looks like a template tag, as by then the rendering step is long past.

Instead you'd need to get Django to generate the base path to the file, and add the rest in your JS. As simple as:

```
var base_path = '{% static "money/data/" %}';
var user = '{{ user.username }}'
var full_url = [base_path, 'highchartpie', user, '.json'].join('')
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this code is in a `.js` file somewhere in your static folder? These files don't get processed by Djangos' template engine so you can't use any template tags of Django related logic in them.

You therefore need a way to get access to the rendered template variable from your javascript. One easy way to do this is to use a hidden input in your html file with the rendered template variable and then use jquery to get the value of that input from your javascript file:

```
<!-- In HTML file -->
<input id="json_path" type="hidden" value="{% static 'money/data/highchartpiesam.json' %}" />

/* In javascript file */
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...
    $.ajax({
    ...
    url: $("#json_path").val(),
    ...
    })
```

Comment: I am using this in the base.html in <script> tag , If i just put string value in it like "{% static 'money/data/highchartpiesam.json' %}" it works , issue is it is not using the value from variable in url: